# Assembly Alias in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

We have used WPFToolKit and PresentationFramework 4.0 in our project. There are some common namespaces in both the dlls(assemblies).To resolve the namespace conflicts, we gave an Alias to WPFToolKit, that helped in code behind(.cs files)

Now in our XAML files, how do we specify the alias.

WPFToolKit DataGrid is not recognized

**Error :
The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

XAML namespace code

```
xmlns:WpfToolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
```

XAML DataGrid

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid Name="BlotterGrid" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build errors got resolved by using Alias as "global,MyAlias" rather than "MyAlias".
Thus in code file external alias "MyAlias" is used whereas in XAML global is used.

Reference :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vseditor/thread/87f0caa0-c57a-4146-a999-c794947ae28e

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
<Window x:Class="New_Project.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:WPFToolKit "
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel>
        <toolkit:DataGrid/>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: No, by alias I mean alias given to assembly while adding reference to it in my project. we can set it in property window for the referenced assembly

Answer (score 0):

XAML alias for referenced dll (Assembly) is definde like that:

```
xmlns:MvvmFramework="clr-namespace:NamespaceName.MvvmFramework.Mvvm;assembly=MvvmFramework"
```

In this case referenced assembly is MvvmFramework.dll

Comment: Hi, the problem is my assembly has alias specified when it was referenced.