# The Type XX exists in both DLLs

Tags: .net, silverlight, namespaces, assemblies, assembly-references

I am developing a silverlight C# app, and I have added a reference to a Microsoft DLL and got the following message:

> The type  exists in both DLLs

Since I am using a control that is defined in both of the DLLs (one is associated with the SDK, the other one I added myself).

After did some research on the internet, I tried to make an alias of both of DLLs, and import them by using `extern alias <alias_name>`. This approach solved some problem in the xaml.cs code behind, but did not really solve the problem in xaml. After I did this, Visual Studio complained that one of the controls (from the DLL I added) is not defined in the namespace.

So I am wondering if there is a way to specify namespace in XML using an alias?

Thank you.

Comment: You're developing a control with the _same samespace used by the framework_, is that? Why?

Comment: No I am not developing but using a control which is defined in two dlls that I am using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463863/assembly-alias-in-xaml)

[MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vseditor/thread/87f0caa0-c57a-4146-a999-c794947ae28e)

You just need to add a second alias to your assembly using comma delimiters.

eg

```
<Aliases>global,alias_name</Aliases>
```

XAML will use the global alias, and you can pick and choose in your classes.

.

If you need to use both assemblies in one place, [I think this solution is the only one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815492/external-alias-in-xaml)

Basically, create two wrapper classes in separate namespaces in your own project for each required class, then reference the wrapper namespaces instead of the conflicting assemblies.

Comment: Hi Thank you, I tried this approach but it does not seem like solving the proble to me. The xaml control element (lets call the control `LL`) is defined in both dlls so I want to do something like specify the `LL` control I used in xaml is from one of the dlls but not from the other, since I dont think I have another chance to specify the name space of the control. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is a good way if you use class from duplicated namespae in C# code (not in XAML)
http://csc-technicalnotes.blogspot.ru/2009/07/type-exists-in-both-dlls.html

Use an external assembly alias.
Specify "Aliases" property of DLL reference.

1. In Visual Studio Solution Explorer, open References folder.
2. Right-click DLL reference, select Properties
3. Enter alias value in "Aliases" property.
4. Example: Alias to MyDLLv1.dll reference could be "LegacyMyDLL".

Specify alias in C# source code:

```
// Old way
using MyNamespace;

// New way
extern alias LegacyMyDLL;
using LegacyMyDLL.MyNamespace;
```